# Modify the page without modifing the url

Tags: url, selectionchanging

I'd like to know how to go to another web page without changing the URL appeared on my browser. What is the best solution to solve my problem?

Comment: You cant, but you can include an iframe that shows another website. Otherwise you'll have to give us more insight on the context youre working in.

Comment: Research keywords: AJAX + HTML5 History API

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe + javascript but you will not be able to load web pages across domains. (most web servers has cross domain restrictions)

Comment: please i would like more explication !